# Object Array search support in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a array of object in elastic search.

I would like to search if a particular field value appears in top 2 position of the array *without using script*.

Imagine my ES data is as follows

```
[
  {
    "_id": "TestID1",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Test1",
        "priority": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Test2",
        "priority": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Test3",
        "priority": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "TestID2",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Test3",
        "priority": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Test9",
        "priority": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Test5",
        "priority": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Test10",
        "priority": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "TestID3",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Test1",
        "priority": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Test2",
        "priority": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Test3",
        "priority": 6
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here I would like to make a query which searches for `_Test3_` *ONLY* within the top 2 elements of the data array.

Searching here would return the result

`_id: TestID2's` data

because only `TestID2` has `Test3` in the top 2 of the data array.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to perform such request directly without using script. The only solution that I can think of is to create a copy of the array field containing only the first 2 elements. You will then be able to search on this field.

You can add an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html) to trim your array automatically.

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/top2_elements
{
    "description": "Create a top2 field containing only the first two values of an array",
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "source": "ctx.top2 = [ctx.data[0], ctx.data[1]]"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```